# (PHP, MySQL) Function only works in 1 of 2 cases, can't find the difference

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I have this function to search entries in a MySQL database:

```
<?php
private function SearchContributors($search) 
    {
    $search_pieces = explode(' ', $search);

    if (count($search_pieces) == 1 )
        {
        $this->db->like('firstname', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('lastname', $search);   
        $result = $this->db->get(); //the line from the error message below
        }   
    
    //Other stuff for 2 and more pieces
    
    return $result;
    }
?>
```

I use the function on two occasions.

**Case A** is a user initiated search and gets the search query from the URL  (`domain.com/contributors/?x=paul`). This works fine.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['x']))
    {
    $x = $_GET['x']; 
    $result = $this->SearchContributors($x);
    }
?>
```

**Case B** is a backup for when a user enters an invalid slug name (`domain.com/contributors/paul` instead of `domain.com/contributors/pauline-surname`) and gets the search query directly:

```
<?php
$this->db->where('slug', $slug);
$result = $this->db->get();    
if ($result->num_rows() == 0)
    {
    $x = str_replace('-', ' ', $slug);
    $result = $this->SearchContributors($x);
    }
?>
```

This returned an MySQL syntax error:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `firstname` LIKE '%paul%' OR `lastname` LIKE '%paul%'' at line 2
>
> SELECT * WHERE `firstname` LIKE '%paul%' OR `lastname` LIKE '%paul%'
>
> Filename: /www/htdocs/w00a94ee/c/controllers/contributors.php
>
> Line Number: 23

The function gets the very same string `paul` in both cases, so why doesn't it work?

**//EDIT**

```
function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database('databasename');
    $this->db->from('tablename');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to specify which table you want to select `FROM`.

```
$this->db->from('tablename');
```

EDIT: The problem is you are adding the `from` in your constructor, then you are calling:

```
$this->db->where('slug', $slug);
$result = $this->db->get();
```

*before* calling `SearchContributors`.  This runs the query and resets the variables.

So, when you call `SearchContributors`, `FROM` is no longer set.

You need to put `$this->db->from('tablename');` inside `SearchContributors` and *not* the constructor.  It's usually a good idea to make model functions self-contained, and not require outside functions (such as `__construct` to call them).

Comment: @user1293977: Which `__construct`?  The Model or the Controller?

Comment: Controller; `class Contributors extends CI_Controller`

Comment: @user1293977: Check my edit: you're calling `$this->db->get()` before calling `SearchContributors`.

Comment: It works, thank you! But isn't to select one table for every function in the class? Like `$this->load->database('databasename')`?

Comment: @user1293977: No, active record doesn't work like that.  When you call `$this->db->get();`, all active record methods are cleared (select, from, where, etc.).

Comment: Ah, that was the part that didn't make sense in my head. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing get('table_name');

```
if (count($search_pieces) == 1 )
    {
    $this->db->like('firstname', $search);
    $this->db->or_like('lastname', $search);   
    $result = $this->db->get('Your_tablename'); //-->>Here you can go
    }
```

See the error

```
select * WHERE......
```

but where is "from Table WHERE"...??i thinks its the problem my dear

Here also you might change

```
$this->db->where('slug', $slug);
$result = $this->db->get('My_Table');
```